# How can I make it say Nothing instead of null on the user's game?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I have a user info command for my bot, and am using `message.author.presence.game` to display what game the user is playing. Whenever they are not playing a game, it displays `null`. How can I make it so it displays Nothing or No game?

Comment: `console.log(message.author.presence.game || 'No game');` Did you do any research before asking this question? [Explanation of logical OR](https://dev.to/banesag/javascript-logical-operators-and-boolean-values-1l07)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `message.author.presence.game || "Nothing"` while displaying text.